# PS script to copy specific files into specific folders

Tags: file, powershell, copy, directory

Here is the scenario, we have bunch of files (list below) in the FolderA and we need to copy each file to it's language folder in the FolderB.

FolderA sample list of files:

- Product_redesign_v2_product_overview_[cs-CZ].txt
- Product_redesign_v2_product_overview_[cs-CZ].xml
- Product_redesign_v2_product_overview_[da-DK].txt
- Product_redesign_v2_product_overview_[da-DK].xml
- Product_redesign_v2_product_overview_[de-CH].txt
- Product_redesign_v2_product_overview_[de-CH].xml

FolderB contains following folders:

- cs-CZ
- da-DK
- de-CH

Goal is to copy all files containing [cs-CZ] in the FolderA into FolderB\cs-CZ folder etc.

In real situation there are dozens/hundreds of files in the FolderA and there is aroud 60 languages in the FolderB. I would update the list of languages in the script on our side.

Thanks for tips!

Comment: Well what have you tried so far?
Please take a look at [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Regular Expression to get the language at the end of the BaseName.

```
## Q:\Test\2018\07\19\SO_51416162.ps1
$FolderA = 'X:\Path\to\FolderA'
$FolderB = 'Y:\Path\to\FolderB'

Get-ChildItem -Path $FolderA |
  Where-Object Basename -match '\[([^\]]+)\]$' | ForEach-Object {
    $Destination  = Join-Path $FolderB $Matches[1]
    IF (Test-Path $Destination){
      $_ | Copy-Item -Destination $Destination -force
    } else {
      "Folder {0} doesn't exist" -f $Destination
    }
  }
```

Sample folder before running script:

```
> tree /F
Auflistung der Ordnerpfade für Volume RamDisk
├───FolderA
│       Product_redesign_v2_product_overview_[cs-CZ].txt
│       Product_redesign_v2_product_overview_[cs-CZ].xml
│       Product_redesign_v2_product_overview_[da-DK].txt
│       Product_redesign_v2_product_overview_[da-DK].xml
│       Product_redesign_v2_product_overview_[de-CH].txt
│       Product_redesign_v2_product_overview_[de-CH].xml
│
└───FolderB
    ├───cs-CZ
    ├───da-DK
    └───de-CH
```

Sample folder after running script:

```
> tree /F
Auflistung der Ordnerpfade für Volume RamDisk
├───FolderA
│       Product_redesign_v2_product_overview_[cs-CZ].txt
│       Product_redesign_v2_product_overview_[cs-CZ].xml
│       Product_redesign_v2_product_overview_[da-DK].txt
│       Product_redesign_v2_product_overview_[da-DK].xml
│       Product_redesign_v2_product_overview_[de-CH].txt
│       Product_redesign_v2_product_overview_[de-CH].xml
│
└───FolderB
    ├───cs-CZ
    │       Product_redesign_v2_product_overview_[cs-CZ].txt
    │       Product_redesign_v2_product_overview_[cs-CZ].xml
    │
    ├───da-DK
    │       Product_redesign_v2_product_overview_[da-DK].txt
    │       Product_redesign_v2_product_overview_[da-DK].xml
    │
    └───de-CH
            Product_redesign_v2_product_overview_[de-CH].txt
            Product_redesign_v2_product_overview_[de-CH].xml
```

Answer (score 0):

My proposition :

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\FolderA" -file -Filter "*[*].*" | %{

#Create directory if dont exists
$NewPath="C:\FolderB\{0}" -f   $_.BaseName.split(@("[", "]"))[1]
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $NewPath -Force | Out-Null

#For escape bracket or other bad caracters
$src = [Management.Automation.WildcardPattern]::Escape($_.FullName)

Copy-Item -Path $src -Destination ("{0}\{1}" -f $NewPath, $_.Name)
}
```